# Get order id and product id while order placed using Observer | Magento 2

Tags: orders, magento2.2.6, event-observer

Hi i need to get the order id and product id while order is generated in magento2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_save_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_save" instance="Learning\Learn\Observer\GetOrderData" />
</event>
</config>
```

in my GetOrderData

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
    try {
            //~ $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $lastorderId = $orderIds[0]; // **returns empty**

         $ordercollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'))->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['eq' => $lastorderId]);
            $ordercollection->setPageSize(1);


          foreach($ordercollection as $order)
          {
            foreach($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) 
            {
               $orderItem->getId();  // **returns empty**
            }
          }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Try this event sales_order_place_after instead of yours.

Comment: @ajwadtaqvi event_sales_order_place also not working

Comment: @SukumarGorai event_sales_order_place also not working